# Understanding the sensitivity of an L3G4200D gyroscope

Tags: datasheet, gyro

I'm hoping someone can help me interpret the meaning of the sensitivity values for the L3G4200D gyroscope. Two small extracts of the datasheet are below:

[image: L3G4200D features extract]

[image: L3G4200D sensitivity extract]

So my question is this. If the gyroscope is configured in the +/- 250dps (degrees per second) range how is it that the sensitivity is only 8.75 mdps/digit?
I would expect that the sensitivity would be 0.00762939453125dps or 7.629mdps/digit.
I calculate this as follows:
16bits = provides a scale of 2^16=65536 unique combinations;
Because the gyro is + and - 250 dps we have a range of 500.
500/65536=0.00762939453125 dps or 7.629mdps/digit

How do you calculate the mdps/digit? and where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your calculations in general look correct, but I suspect they are not using the full range to get 'nicer' numbers per reading. Sometimes it's good to have numbers that are more easily handled with integer math rather than a slightly higher resolution (which is probably mainly noise anyway).

Comment: I agree that noise is an element in every circuit but it doesn't make sense to me that the scale is so different. This implies that in 250dps mode I may actually be measuring 286.72dps? 32768*0.008.75 Hence my confusion over the scale.

Comment: The answer below looks like the real reason to me. It is true you could possibly get a reading of 286, but that's something you should treat as an 'out of range' condition. If they made the scaling exact without an error flag of some sort you'd have no way of knowing the difference between 250 and something above that went off-scale. Most accelerometers I've used are similar and do report something above the normal range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@PeterJ is on the right track, but I doubt that it has anything to do with making the numbers "nice". More likely, the manufacturer wanted to make sure that the useful (linear) part of the analog sensor range always falls within the ADC range despite manufacturing tolerances. To that end, they gave themselves a 15% margin (7.5% at each end). This would agree with some of the other numbers in the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00265057.pdf), such as initial offset (DVoff) of +/-4% and a worst-case temperature offset (OffDr) of +/-2.4% at the extremes.

In other words, this sensor needs to be calibrated (zeroed) and temperature-compensated (for both offset and gain) in your application in order to achieve the best level of performance. The "extra" range of the digital output allows the sensor to express the full-scale rates in both directions without saturating, even when these errors all add up in the same direction.